# Why is COUNTIF returning a 0? It should be returning a value of 8

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a fairly simple countif function that counts how many items are 90 days old or more.

```
=COUNTIF(PROCFilter!H2:H,">=90")
```

But all this is returning is a value of 0, when I know that there are at least 8 items over 90 in that column. I've tried removing the "=" and just having ">90" and it still returns a 0. The column in question is formatted numerically. My only thought is that there are a few cells in column H that have a dash ("-") instead of a numerical value. Would this be throwing off the entire function? Oddly enough, if I put `=COUNTIF(PROCFilter!H2:H,"=100")` it returns the correct value of 1.

I'm anticipating an obvious answer, but I've been staring at this sheet forever and I lost my brainpower.

Comment: "The column in question is formatted numerically."  
I believe it is formatted as text instead...try to test it with ISNUMBER("the cell with 100 inside")

Answer (score 2):

[image: Text vs Number]

the only chance you get those results is that column H contains text and not numbers